# Мне нужно сохранить список после написания задач в TODO List. Как тут использовать LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>TODO App</title>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container mb-5">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">My todo</a>
          <a href="dad.html" class="nav-link">Mom's todo</a>
          <a href="mom.html" class="nav-link">Dad's todo</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    
        <div class="container" id="todo-app">
    
        </div>
        <script defer src="todo-app.js"></script>
        <!--
        <div id="todo-app">
            <h1>TODO List</h1>
            <form id="todo-form">
                <input type="text" id="todo-input" placeholder="Add a new task">
                <button type="submit" id="add-button" disabled>Add</button>
            </form>
            <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
        </div>
     -->
    
    
    </body>
    </html>

    
 (function() {
    function createAppTitle (title) {
      let appTitle = document.createElement('h2');
      appTitle.innerHTML = title;
      return appTitle;
    }
    // const todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];
    // function saveLocal(){
    //   localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    // }

    function createTodoItemForm () {
      let form = document.createElement('form');
      let input = document.createElement('input');
      let buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div');
      let button = document.createElement('button');

      form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3');
      input.classList.add('form-control');
      input.placeholder = 'Введите название нового дела';
      buttonWrapper.classList.add('input-group-append');
      button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
      button.textContent = 'Добавить дело';

      buttonWrapper.append(button);
      form.appendChild(input);
      form.append(buttonWrapper);
      return{
        form,
        input,
        button
      };

    }

    function createTodoList () {
      let list = document.createElement('ul');
      list.classList.add('list-group');
      return list;
    }
    // document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function () {
    //   let container = document.getElementById('todo-app');

    //   let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle('Список дел');
    //   let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
    //   let todoList = createTodoList();

    //   container.append(todoAppTitle);
    //   container.append(todoItemForm.form);
    //   container.append(todoList);
    // });

    function createTodoItem (name) {
      let item = document.createElement('li');
      let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div');
      let doneButton = document.createElement('button');
      let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

      item.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
      item.textContent = name;

      buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group','btn-group-sm');
      doneButton.classList.add('btn','btn-success');
      doneButton.textContent = 'Done';
      deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
      deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';

      buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
      buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
      item.append(buttonGroup);

      return{
        item,
        doneButton,
        deleteButton
      };
    }

    function createTodoApp (container, title = 'Todo') {

      let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
      let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
      let todoList = createTodoList();

      container.append(todoAppTitle);
      container.append(todoItemForm.form);
      container.append(todoList);

      todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!todoItemForm.input.value){
          return;
        }

      let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value);
      todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
      });
      todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete')) {
          todoItem.item.remove();
        }
      });
      todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        todoItemForm.input.value = '';
      })

    }
    window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      createTodoApp(document.getElementById("todo-app"), "To-Do");
     localStorage.setItem("saveToDo",JSON.stringify(createTodoApp(name)));

    });
console.log(createTodoApp);
    //  localStorage.setItem('createTodoApp', JSON.stringify(createTodoApp));
    //  console.log(createTodoApp);
    function loadLocal() {
      // const savedData = localStorage.getItem("todo-app");
      if (createTodoApp) {
        const savedList = JSON.parse(savedData);
        // Восстановите элементы списка дел и их состояния (например, выполнено/не выполнено).
        savedList.forEach((itemData) => {
          const todoItem = createTodoItem(itemData.name);
          if (itemData.isDone) {
            todoItem.item.classList.add("list-group-item-success");
          }
          todoList.appendChild(todoItem.item);
        });
      }
 }
console.log(loadLocal);

    // document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    //   createTodoApp(document.getElementById('my-todos'), 'my-todos');
    //   createTodoApp(document.getElementById('mom-todos'), 'Mom-todos');
    //   createTodoApp(document.getElementById('dad-todos'), 'Dad-todos');
    //   });

  })();
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема? В коде не видно попыток сохранения значений в localStorage. По сути, там где вы получаете финальный список тудушек, вам надо выполнить `localStorage.setItem('name', value: string)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>TODO App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mb-5">
    <nav class="nav">
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container" id="todo-app">
</div>
<script>
    (function() {
    function createAppTitle(title) {
        let appTitle = document.createElement('h2');
        appTitle.innerHTML = title;
        return appTitle;
    }

    function createTodoItemForm() {
        let form = document.createElement('form');
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        let buttonWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        let button = document.createElement('button');

        form.classList.add('input-group', 'mb-3');
        input.classList.add('form-control', 'me-2');
        input.placeholder = 'Введите название нового дела';
        buttonWrapper.classList.add('input-group-append');
        button.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary');
        button.textContent = 'Добавить дело';

        buttonWrapper.append(button);
        form.appendChild(input);
        form.append(buttonWrapper);
        return {
        form,
        input,
        button
        };
    }

    function createTodoList() {
        let list = document.createElement('ul');
        list.classList.add('list-group');
        return list;
    }

    function createTodoItem(name, isDone = false) {
        let item = document.createElement('li');
        let buttonGroup = document.createElement('div');
        let doneButton = document.createElement('button');
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

        item.classList.add('list-group-item', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-between', 'align-items-center');
        item.textContent = name;
        item.dataset.taskName = name; // Добавляем атрибут данных с текстом задачи

        if (isDone) {
        item.classList.add('list-group-item-success');
        }

        buttonGroup.classList.add('btn-group', 'btn-group-sm');
        doneButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-success');
        doneButton.textContent = 'Done';
        deleteButton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger');
        deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';

        buttonGroup.append(doneButton);
        buttonGroup.append(deleteButton);
        item.append(buttonGroup);

        return {
        item,
        doneButton,
        deleteButton,
        isDone
        };
    }

    // Функция для сохранения задач в localStorage
    function saveTodoList(todoList) {
        if (todoList) {
        const todoListItems = Array.from(todoList.children).map(item => {
            return {
            text: item.dataset.taskName,
            isDone: item.classList.contains('list-group-item-success')
            };
        });
        localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(todoListItems));
        }
    }

    // Функция для восстановления задач из localStorage
    function restoreTodoList(todoList) {
        const savedData = localStorage.getItem('todoList');
        if (savedData) {
        const todoListItems = JSON.parse(savedData);
        todoListItems.forEach(itemData => {
            const todoItem = createTodoItem(itemData.text, itemData.isDone);
            todoList.append(todoItem.item);
            setupTodoItemEventListeners(todoItem);
        });
        }
    }

    function createTodoApp(container, title = 'Todo') {
        let todoAppTitle = createAppTitle(title);
        let todoItemForm = createTodoItemForm();
        let todoList = createTodoList();

        // Восстановление списка задач при загрузке страницы
        restoreTodoList(todoList);

        container.append(todoAppTitle);
        container.append(todoItemForm.form);
        container.append(todoList);

        todoItemForm.form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!todoItemForm.input.value) {
            return;
        }

        let todoItem = createTodoItem(todoItemForm.input.value);
        todoList.append(todoItem.item);
        setupTodoItemEventListeners(todoItem);

        todoItemForm.input.value = '';

        // Сохранение обновленного списка задач
        saveTodoList(todoList);
        });
    }

    function setupTodoItemEventListeners(todoItem) {
        todoItem.doneButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        todoItem.item.classList.toggle('list-group-item-success');
        todoItem.isDone = !todoItem.isDone; // Обновление состояния выполнения задачи
        // Сохранение обновленного списка задач
        saveTodoList(todoItem.item.parentNode);
        });

        todoItem.deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete')) {
            todoItem.item.remove();
            // Удаление задачи из localStorage
            removeFromLocalStorage(todoItem.item.dataset.taskName);
        }
        });
    }

    // Функция для удаления задачи из localStorage
    function removeFromLocalStorage(itemText) {
        const savedData = localStorage.getItem('todoList');
        if (savedData) {
        const todoListItems = JSON.parse(savedData);
        const updatedList = todoListItems.filter(item => item.text !== itemText);
        localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(updatedList));
        }
    }

    window.createTodoApp = createTodoApp;
    })();

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    createTodoApp(document.getElementById("todo-app"), "To-Do");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Этот код позволяет пользователю добавлять, отмечать как выполненные и удалять задачи, а также сохранять состояние списка задач в localStorage, чтобы оно оставалось после перезагрузки страницы.